# Popen() not working in script but working in interpreter

Tags: python, multiprocessing, popen

i have a script action.py which will take a file name as command line argument and do some processing on that file.
i want to run this script multiple times with different input files . i used Popen() command to run the script which is surprisingly working fine in interpreter but does not work if  i run the script .

```
for i in range(n):
    Popen("python action.py input" +str(i)+ ".txt")
```

if i copy this code in the interpreter it works fine and spawn n processes but does not do any thing when i run the whole script in pycharm.

Comment: There is no `Popen()` function in Python, unless you wrote your own. Please check your code for validity. As a side note, why not simply call the functions from that script?

Comment: Have you imported popen using `from os import popen`?

Answer (score 0):

I think You are mentioning about the subprocess module.This code might work:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['python','script','argv1','argv2'])
```

For Further references read the [Popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) documentation.

Hope This Helps